# reading only the first line of the file

Tags: vb.net, search, eof

I'm trying to read from a txt file and then display the contents of the file in corresponding text boxes, the fields are separated by a comma. However, it is only reading the first line of the file and i am not sure how to correct this. Here is my code for vb.net:

```
FileOpen(1, "MembersArea.txt", OpenMode.Input) 'OPEN FILE FOR READING'
    Dim crosscheck As String
    Dim flag As Boolean
    crosscheck = Val(txtCrosscheck.Text)
    flag = False
    While Not EOF(1) 'OPEN FILE AT BEGINNING'
        Input(1, Member_ID) 'READ LINE
        Input(1, Forename)
        Input(1, Surname)
        Input(1, Addressline1)
        Input(1, Addressline2)
        Input(1, Town)
        Input(1, County)
        Input(1, Postcode)
        If Member_ID = crosscheck Then
            flag = True
        Else
        End If
        Exit While
    End While
    If flag = True Then
        txtCrosscheck.Enabled = False
        btncrosscheck.Enabled = False
        btnaddlog.Enabled = True
        cmbevent.Enabled = True
        dtpevent.Enabled = True
        txtheartratebefore.Enabled = True
        txtheartrateafter.Enabled = True
        cmbevent.Focus()
    Else
        MsgBox("Member ID does not exist. Please enter an existing Member ID to add Training Log")
    End If

    nameconcat = Forename & " " & Surname


    FileClose(1)
```

thank you!

Comment: You are calling `Exit While`, so it will only read up to that point, wherever that happens to be in your file.

Comment: Also, where did you get this code?  It looks like code leftover from VB6 days.  You should read how to do it the .net way: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and if you are using a CSV, there is the TextFieldParser, which can parse the CSV for you:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: These days we use the `System.IO.StreamReader` for files.

Comment: @das_l I would suggest rewriting the code using the `TextFieldParser` if your input is truly CSV, as that will save you time in the long run.

Comment: A database would be a better system for this. Where you can query with search terms and it would return the one record you wanted or nothing(based on search criteria).

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your problem.
I think I understood that the first line of the file contains various information separated by "," like this: "one,two,three,four,five" and you want to extract these fields and put them in separate textbox.
to separate these fields is sufficient split command

```
        Dim riga As String = "one,two,three,four,five"
        Dim fields() As String = riga.Split(",")
```

Now:

```
   fields(0)="one"
   fields(1)="two"
   fields(2)="three"
   fields(3)="four"
   fields(4)="five"
```

so:

```
   textbox1.text=fields(0)
   etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

As John Koerner wrote, you're calling Exit While, which will exit after the first iteration.

Also, in VB.NET, I believe it would be better to use a streamreader for this purpose.
**EDIT: A note, you'll need to add an import for System.IO in order to use a streamreader.**

You can add that import with this line at the top of your code:

```
Imports System.IO
```

I don't have much experience in writing and reading CSV's, so I've created a function to read until the next comma.
Declare a streamreader using Private.

```
Private streamMembersArea As StreamReader

    Private Function ReadInfo()
    Dim strField As String = ""
    Do
        strField += streamMembersArea.Read()

    Loop Until strField.Contains(",")
    strField = strField.Remove(strField.Length - 1, 1)
    Return strField
End Function
```

This should actually eliminate the need for you to call While Not EOF, however if you're not sure that all fields will be entered into the file, I would recommend checking for it...

You could do this by calling:

```
While streamMembersArea.Peek <> -1 'Checks whether there is another character available, if not (like at the end of a file), it returns -1
... ' Place the following code here
...
End While
```

You could do this the following way:

```
'Declare variables
    Dim crosscheck As String
    Dim flag As Boolean
    'Removed Dim for streamReader, now a private, above

    'crosscheck 
    crosscheck = Val(txtCrosscheck.Text)

    'flag
    flag = False

    'Open file for input
    streamMembersArea = IO.File.OpenText("MembersArea.txt")

    'Read info into variables
    Member_ID = ReadInfo()
    Forename = ReadInfo()
    Surname = ReadInfo()
    Addressline1 = ReadInfo()
    Addressline2 = ReadInfo()
    Town = ReadInfo()
    County = ReadInfo()
    Postcode = ReadInfo()

    'Close stream
    streamMembersArea.Close() ' Closes the file, make sure you include this.

    'Validate Member ID
    If Member_ID = crosscheck Then
        flag = True
    Else ' Not needed, but fine either way
    End If
    'Exit While <- Commented out, no more 'While' loop, unnecessary now
    'End While <- Not used anymore either

    If flag = True Then
        txtCrosscheck.Enabled = False
        btncrosscheck.Enabled = False
        btnaddlog.Enabled = True
        cmbevent.Enabled = True
        dtpevent.Enabled = True
        txtheartratebefore.Enabled = True
        txtheartrateafter.Enabled = True
        cmbevent.Focus()
    Else
        MsgBox("Member ID does not exist. Please enter an existing Member ID to add Training Log")
    End If

    nameconcat = Forename & " " & Surname


    'FileClose(1) <- No longer needed, closed stream earlier
```

Please let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: I'm sorry, you'll need to import System.IO. You can do this by adding this line to the top of your code with the other imports " Imports System.IO " (without quotes). Sorry, I noticed you said comma's afterwards.... I'll try and modify code to use comma's

Comment: @das_l , I've made the edits necessary for this to work with commas. Please include the function I added which will read every character up until the comma, return a string, and then upon the next read will skip the comma and start again. **You will need to remove the Dim declaration for the streamreader and include the private that I added to the answer at the top.**
You will need to recopy the code for the rest of it, as I've updated it to use that function. Let me know if this works please :)

Comment: I don't think that while loop I mentioned above is necessary, but yes you could put that code within the loop and shouldn't have issues...I'm sorry, I had forgotten that the Peek function wouldn't return the actual value of the character.  I'm going to update the function to loop until it adds a comma to the field, and then simply remove it. That should work... Will update in 1 min.

Comment: @das_l I've updated the function so that now it will read everything up to and including the next comma, and then remove the comma from the end, and return the string. Please try this.

Comment: I'm confused now. Could you tell me which line it's giving you that error message on?

Comment: @das_l I think it may be having an issue with the +=, I would recommend trying " strField = strField & streamMembersArea.Read() " instead and see if that resolves the issue. Sorry for the repeated errors XD I'm a beginner as well.

Comment: Well, like they'd mentioned before, it's a lot harder to create a CSV parser than you'd imagine; and there are a lot of them available... I'm pretty much avoiding them wherever possible in my applications. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.